# How to install Microsoft Media Foundation programmatically?

Tags: c++, video, windows-installer, ms-media-foundation

I'm using [Microsoft Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk) APIs to access a web camera. This works, except that the Media Foundation is not installed by default on all versions of Windows. For instance, it's available as an optional component for Windows 10 N, Windows 11 N, etc.

In that case, if it's not installed, [`MFStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfstartup) will return `E_NOTIMPL` and one needs to refer to [KB2703761](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-windows-media-feature-pack-for-n-and-kn-versions-of-all-windows-8-editions-4a96f5a9-e3ce-dc37-bff9-ff4fb3369aa2).

The problem for me is how to install it from the installer for my app? The media installer that they give in KB2703761 does not work on Windows 10 or 11. And all I can find is [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions-c1c6fffa-d052-8338-7a79-a4bb980a700a) with a long list of options.

Does anyone know if there's a unified installer for it that one can use in their own MSI bootstrapper?

Comment: **Do not waste any moment of time with Windows N.** The install count is pretty close to absolute zero, and it might even be a negative number.  In 25+ years of making really well known Windows apps, my teams never tested on Windows N. Often we didn't even know if our code would properly install or run on it. And in the time we knew it didn't, product support never got any calls about it either.

Comment: @selbie Thanks. So even MSFT doesn't know the install base for the N flavors of Windows, hah  You work for them, right.

Comment: Unified installer? no. These versions exist for legal reasons (monopoly trials like 20 years ago, etc.) so they are a pain for Microsoft they won't make it easy (and for developers ...). But you can find the packages one by one, for example: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48231 You should ask superuser.com instead.

Comment: @SimonMourier yeah it's a royal pain for sure. This means that I need to determine those crazy Windows versions that they are using now, and then have all those packages in my installer. Which will balloon it quite a lot. What do you do when you use MFT in your apps?

Comment: @c00000fd - I just told you what the verified install base was for Windows N Skus in my previous comment.

Comment: I just report to the user that the machine needs the Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows "X" be installed.

Comment: IMO this whole problem is not worth any attention. Like @SimonMourier suggests I would just add a check and suggest to install Desktop Experience, or whatever this feature is called, manually in order to proceed and to have required parts of MF installed.

Comment: @RomanR. yeah, I got it. Since the install base for N flavor is very small I wouldn't worry about dragging in the multitude of different installers for the MF. I'll just show an error message from the installer like Simon suggested.